# Python PyQt4 slider with tick labels

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am new to PyQt4 and i am making a gui with QSlider.

By default the QSlider doesnt show you the values of your ticks. I searched and didnt find an easy way to do it, so is it possible or do i have to make it manualy?

Comment: I mean i have a range of values between 1-10, and i want it to be visible below the ticks so i can easily choose the value i want

Answer (score 3):

I've cooked up a solution that deals with adding labels to sliders, in vertical or horizontal orientations.

Result screenshot:

[image]

Code here (note that there are some import changes between PyQt4 and 5).

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyle, QStyleOptionSlider
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPoint, Qt


class LabeledSlider(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum, interval=1, orientation=Qt.Horizontal,
            labels=None, parent=None):
        super(LabeledSlider, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        levels=range(minimum, maximum+interval, interval)
        if labels is not None:
            if not isinstance(labels, (tuple, list)):
                raise Exception("<labels> is a list or tuple.")
            if len(labels) != len(levels):
                raise Exception("Size of <labels> doesn't match levels.")
            self.levels=list(zip(levels,labels))
        else:
            self.levels=list(zip(levels,map(str,levels)))

        if orientation==Qt.Horizontal:
            self.layout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        elif orientation==Qt.Vertical:
            self.layout=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        else:
            raise Exception("<orientation> wrong.")

        # gives some space to print labels
        self.left_margin=10
        self.top_margin=10
        self.right_margin=10
        self.bottom_margin=10

        self.layout.setContentsMargins(self.left_margin,self.top_margin,
                self.right_margin,self.bottom_margin)

        self.sl=QtWidgets.QSlider(orientation, self)
        self.sl.setMinimum(minimum)
        self.sl.setMaximum(maximum)
        self.sl.setValue(minimum)
        if orientation==Qt.Horizontal:
            self.sl.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksBelow)
            self.sl.setMinimumWidth(300) # just to make it easier to read
        else:
            self.sl.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksLeft)
            self.sl.setMinimumHeight(300) # just to make it easier to read
        self.sl.setTickInterval(interval)
        self.sl.setSingleStep(1)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.sl)

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        super(LabeledSlider,self).paintEvent(e)

        style=self.sl.style()
        painter=QPainter(self)
        st_slider=QStyleOptionSlider()
        st_slider.initFrom(self.sl)
        st_slider.orientation=self.sl.orientation()

        length=style.pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_SliderLength, st_slider, self.sl)
        available=style.pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_SliderSpaceAvailable, st_slider, self.sl)

        for v, v_str in self.levels:

            # get the size of the label
            rect=painter.drawText(QRect(), Qt.TextDontPrint, v_str)

            if self.sl.orientation()==Qt.Horizontal:
                # I assume the offset is half the length of slider, therefore
                # + length//2
                x_loc=QStyle.sliderPositionFromValue(self.sl.minimum(),
                        self.sl.maximum(), v, available)+length//2

                # left bound of the text = center - half of text width + L_margin
                left=x_loc-rect.width()//2+self.left_margin
                bottom=self.rect().bottom()

                # enlarge margins if clipping
                if v==self.sl.minimum():
                    if left<=0:
                        self.left_margin=rect.width()//2-x_loc
                    if self.bottom_margin<=rect.height():
                        self.bottom_margin=rect.height()

                    self.layout.setContentsMargins(self.left_margin,
                            self.top_margin, self.right_margin,
                            self.bottom_margin)

                if v==self.sl.maximum() and rect.width()//2>=self.right_margin:
                    self.right_margin=rect.width()//2
                    self.layout.setContentsMargins(self.left_margin,
                            self.top_margin, self.right_margin,
                            self.bottom_margin)

            else:
                y_loc=QStyle.sliderPositionFromValue(self.sl.minimum(),
                        self.sl.maximum(), v, available, upsideDown=True)

                bottom=y_loc+length//2+rect.height()//2+self.top_margin-3
                # there is a 3 px offset that I can't attribute to any metric

                left=self.left_margin-rect.width()
                if left<=0:
                    self.left_margin=rect.width()+2
                    self.layout.setContentsMargins(self.left_margin,
                            self.top_margin, self.right_margin,
                            self.bottom_margin)

            pos=QPoint(left, bottom)
            painter.drawText(pos, v_str)

        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame=QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ha=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    frame.setLayout(ha)

    w = LabeledSlider(1, 10 , 1, orientation=Qt.Horizontal)

    ha.addWidget(w)
    frame.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there's no easy way to do this. You will have to make it manually. I just had to do it too, so you can have my implementation. Take into account that I only re-implemented what I needed, I hacked a bit the alignments and the valueChanged() API exhibits a very different behaviour.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import QSlider, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
__author__ = 'Andres'


class QCustomSlider(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, sliderOrientation=None):
        super(QCustomSlider, self).__init__()
        self._slider = QSlider(sliderOrientation)

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        self._labelTicksWidget = QWidget(self)
        self._labelTicksWidget.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self._labelTicksWidget.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.layout().addWidget(self._slider)
        self.layout().addWidget(self._labelTicksWidget)

    def setTickLabels(self, listWithLabels):
        lengthOfList = len(listWithLabels)
        for index, label in enumerate(listWithLabels):
            label = QLabel(str(label))
            label.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            if index > lengthOfList/3:
                label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            if index > 2*lengthOfList/3:
                label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
            self._labelTicksWidget.layout().addWidget(label)

    def setRange(self, mini, maxi):
        self._slider.setRange(mini, maxi)

    def setPageStep(self, value):
        self._slider.setPageStep(value)

    def setTickInterval(self, value):
        self._slider.setTickInterval(value)

    def setTickPosition(self, position):
        self._slider.setTickPosition(position)

    def setValue(self, value):
        self._slider.setValue(value)

    def onValueChangedCall(self, function):
        self._slider.valueChanged.connect(function)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a simple but amateurish method: You can use Qt Designer to help you set up a slider, and add text labels under the slider in the Qt Designer. You just need to adjust the position of the labels, making the text labels align with the slider.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).